# Will we ever see a laptop that looks and functions like a tablet?

Tags: tools, hardware-recommendation

I work freelance and sometimes travel & work at the same time. I am looking to replace my 4-yo Dell laptop, which is quite a hassle to travel with at over 2kg, with a similarly equipped but smaller device, however I am holding back because I am still not able to get a device that would make work & travel easier.

What I am wondering is will we ever see a *Macbook Pro#* equivalent professional laptop in the shape of a tablet like the *iPad Pro*? What this means is I am looking for a powerful tool capable of running professional software but as a single object, **without** the flap, the built-in keyboard, etc. Something that can connect **externally** to a keyboard, mouse, ips monitor, etc, but still look like a tablet and work like a laptop, be able to run native Adobe software, etc.

Basicly something like the *iPad Pro* that does everything the *Macbook Pro* does today.

*#Note: this is not a question of Mac vs Pc. I just gave the example above because everybody is familiar with these Apple products.*

Comment: Well I mean Microsoft Surface Pro does already exist, so I'm going to say yes.

Comment: Actually didn't know Surface had a _Pro_ version. thanks

Comment: I regretted not mentioning this... Wacom has their  [Cintiq Companion 2 and their newest thing Cintiq MobileStudio Pro](http://wacom.com/en-us/products/pen-computers). They're pretty damn expensive though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Lenovo Yoga](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/yoga/) or [Microsoft Surface](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/surface). These are 2-in-1 devices, that combine the functionality of a laptop and tablet. They run Windows 10 and as far as I know, support graphics software.

Comment: Also, more pricey version of Dell XPS 15 laptop have built in touchscreen and is a real powerhouse. But it is, as I've mentioned - expensive.

Comment: I know about these. Just edited my question to make it clear I am not looking for recommendation on any current devices on the market, which I am aware of. thanks

Comment: So a computer with touchscreen, without built in keyboard but with ability to connect extensions to it? I'd say that Surface still fits into your description. It has DisplayPort, so it can connect to monitor, you can connect keyboard and mouse via USB or Bluetooth and it runs OS that supports Adobe apps. Of course the technology could be refined and perfected, but I wouldn't quite say we are not there yet.

Comment: Actually didn't know Surface had a _Pro_ version. thanks